# How to build sphinx 4 cmu

Tags: java, build, sphinx4

Recently I downloaded sphinx4.

I opened the zip and there was shpinx4-master.
It appears that my project requires streamspeechrecognizer. I searched and I found that in the sphinx4-master there is sphinx4-core which in there there is the streamspeechrecognizer class.
I tried to import it to my project and I can't. How can I import the sphinx4-core to my project?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You seem to have downloaded the whole repository, and not the library that you only need.

Comment: Where can I download the library?

Answer (score 0):

Look at the download page on the wiki here, http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/wiki/download/.

But it seems to be down at the moment. If you can't access it now, try accessing it tomorrow.

Comment: Thank you very much sir.